# Why is a free factor of a group malnormal in that group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

For a subgroup $K \leq H$, we say $K$ is a free factor of $H$ if $H$ can be written as the free product $K * C$ for some $C \leq H$, i.e. if we have the presentations $K = \langle S_K \mid R_K \rangle$, $C = \langle S_C \mid R_C \rangle$, then $H = \langle S_K, S_C \mid R_K, R_C \rangle$.

We say that $K$ is malnormal in $H$ if $\forall g \in H \setminus K$, we have that $g^{-1} K g \cap K = 1$.

In a paper I am reading, it is stated that every free factor is trivially malnormal. I've been trying to convince myself that this is true for quite some time and have not been able to. I would appreciate it if someone could explain to me why this is true.

Comment: Which paper are you referring to?

Comment: This should follow almost directly from the description of the free group $H = K * C$ as reduced words in $K$ and $C$, have you tried it this way?

Comment: @Rushy Say $K$ has generators $S_K := \{ k_1 , \dots , k_n \}$ and $C$ has generators $S_C := \{ c_1 , \dots , c_m \}$. Fix $g \in H \setminus K$, which by definition of free product can be written as $g = g_1 g_2 \dots g_r$, $g_i \in S_K^{\pm} \cup S_C^{\pm}$. 

Suppose $g^{-1} K g \cap K$ has a nontrivial element of the form $g k g^{-1}$. Then $g_1 g_2 \dots g_r k g_r^{-1} \dots g_1^{-1} \in K$, and at least one of the $g_i$'s has to be in $H$ by assumption that $g \notin K$. This would mean there is a relation between elements of $S_K$ and $S_C$, which is a contradiction. Is this correct?

Comment: @Shaun The paper is "Stallings Foldings and Subgroups of Free Groups" by Ilya Kapovich & Alexei Myasnikov, and the claim in question is made in the proof of Lemma 13.3

Comment: Pretty much yeah, you can argue without generators by writing $g = k_1c_1\cdots k_rc_r$, then for any $k \in K$, we have $g^{-1}kg = c_r^{-1}\cdots c_1^{-1}k_1^{-1}kk_1c_1\cdots c_r$, now if $k = 1$ then evidently $g^{-1}kg = 1$, if $k \neq 1$ then $k_1^{-1}kk_1 \neq 1$ and this word can't be reduced to something in $K$ (since at least one of the $c_i \neq 1$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a geometric proof assuming basis Bass-Serre theory.

Write $H=K\ast L$. By Bass-Serre theory, there exists a action of $H$ on a tree with trivial edge stabilizers, with a vertex $v$ whose stabilizer is $H_v=K$.

For $h\in H$, the stabilizer of $hv$ is $hH_vh^{-1}=hKh^{-1}$. If $h\notin K$, $hv\neq v$ and $H\cap hKh^{-1}$ fixes the whole segment $[v,hv]$. Since edge stabilizers are trivial, it follows that $H\cap hKh^{-1}=\{1\}$.